# Find the Number With the Highest Sum of Neighbors

Tags: code-golf, number, matrix

## The Challenge

Given a grid of numbers (10 <= N <= 99)
Return number with the highest sum of the four numbers adjacent to it; that is the numbers above, below, right, and left of the number, but not itself.

1. The number itself does not count, only its four neighbors.
2. A number on the edge *should* be treated as though the missing number is a 0.
3. I will design the test to avoid ties.
4. Numbers will not repeat.
5. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

## Example

Given

```
56 98 32 96
12 64 45 31
94 18 83 71
```

Return

```
18
```

## A Real Test

Given

```
98 95 67 66 57 16 40 94 84 37
87 14 19 34 83 99 97 78 50 36
18 44 29 47 21 86 24 15 91 61
60 41 51 26 10 58 11 62 55 71
42 85 56 12 46 81 93 65 49 77
89 13 74 39 54 76 92 33 82 90
96 88 70 79 80 28 25 20 75 68
38 63 17 72 53 48 73 30 45 69
64 35 32 31 23 43 22 52 27 59
```

Return

```
13
```

Given

```
82 43 79 81 94 36 17 64 58
24 52 13 87 70 18 28 61 69
16 99 75 21 50 44 89 90 51
49 80 63 31 54 65 41 55 38
67 91 76 78 23 86 83 14 73
46 68 62 77 34 48 20 74 10
33 35 26 97 59 66 25 37 32
12 92 84 27 85 56 22 40 45
96 15 98 53 39 30 88 71 29
60 42 11 57 95 19 93 72 47
```

Return

```
15
```

Comment: "*A number on the edge **can** be treated as though the missing number is a 0.*" - That implies we have a choice as to how to handle numbers on an edge of the grid. Can we therefore choose to wrap around to the other side of the grid?

Comment: @Shaggy No.  That might change the expected result.  Let's all do it the same way.  Text updated s/can/should/

Comment: *waiting for the inevitable MATL answer*

Comment: I notice most of the solutions mutate the input in some way.  Is that conventional here?  My (yet to be posted) solution includes the bytes required to mutate the input and I'm wondering why many others do not.

Comment: @Umbrella We generally don't care if the input gets modified. We're interested in short code, not clean code. So long as the output is right, we tend to be pretty permissive.

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>20</s> <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
t1Y6Z+tuX>=)
```

Saved 5 bytes thanks to Emigna, 2 thanks to Giuseppe, and another thanks to Luis Mendo.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY87Um1RCAWn0qn1ks0f6tRzHH7KwFyz6/iPGEIvoPn@fHzd90Ne8@3f4@fl@f/Tfb9PM0EWmUQhiR/GacfqorflyGDbMmaYopo4WF5I444OXqjQiW46GCHlIg8uhKCJHKKRBUoEtdiVDmKZ4kkLY2TgQ/3dHsSoFRnCqWQUM1qZczE70dShhj5oo4Fuue/0hTVpyNruPcM3atgKLZ5V27WB7cK1W2zo5hQtYj5@AQ)

#### Explanation

```
t1Y6Z+tuX>=)
t                  Duplicate the (implicit) input.
 1Y6               Push the array [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0].
    Z+             Convolve with the input.
       uX>         Get the maximum unique element...
      t   =        ... and compare elementwise.
           )       Index into the input.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>31</s> <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>24</s> 23 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

-2 thanks to Cows quack. -1 thanks to ngn.

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Takes a matrix as argument. Assumes `⎕IO` (**I**ndex **O**rigin) to be `0`, which is default on many systems.

```apl
{⊃⍒,(+/--/)⊢∘,⌺3 3⊢⍵}⊃,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JZK9apRBFIZ7r@ItFXfJ/Jz5ObVNUgWMNxCQtQloK2IVCLK4IQoBa2/ARhtLL2VuZH3OBpaF@b53vnmf58z1h5vt24/XN@/fHdf948XluntIx09rf7sO3zfPX55tt2cv1v7n@vJjs77@raqxOPz5TGJz3JFeh/unjfvbf7/quvvG6ur1K/7fnF9cHXeqsnX43bp8qhZ5Vy7qJmuqWW7KU7Nq5Gc7uXIiTNKb@lDvakO5y1Ikp6kOTZ6wy1UtNrrLh8ZUS6o9vmam4rKhkjW7CuEmz@r8kiyrZRWSSW0q87CoNQrIimZTOzW0rkm9qt5krsG5tKMnHVzNNCAqqlUTqBRcc2okDddMKlOlqbAEBPCpXpXpyVkYIYnLFBK6h43aQg5CCm@rCrGiMtQcLTR1tHAQr@L7J28BO2IvFDCSpx5y6IAECgSvhz0UUQMbKEIOIBRGgp2qUoxzIQrSHCqi7QhjMCKWSmhENdqpjRmIkIYTRgBLYFq0xAYguPVoHuNDAiMDDaXoYoJAPUmG0U4G4kq0uB6YwS1awmSOIca8SsyIa8CVYOhMBIc2/gM)

`,` ravel (flatten) the input

`{`…`}⊃` pick an element from that according to the result of the following function:

`⊢⍵` yield the argument (separates `3 3` from `⍵`)

…`⌺3 3` apply the following function to each 3-by-3 neighbourhood:

`⊢∘,` ignore the edge-information in favour of the ravelled (flattened) neighbourhood

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function to those

`-/` the alternating sum (lit. right-associative minus reduction)

`+/-` subtract that from the sum (this gives the sum of every other element)

`,` ravel (flatten) that (the neighbourhood sums)

`⍒` produce the indices which would sort that

`⊃` pick the first (i.e. the index of the highest sum)

Comment: That was fast.  Did you come prepared? ;)

Comment: @Umbrella No, I just use a programming language which is quick to program in.

Comment: How's this `{⊃⍒,{+/1↓⍉4 2⍴⍵}⌺3 3⊢⍵}⊃,`? Edit: or even `{⊃⍒,{⊢/+⌿4 2⍴⍵}⌺3 3⊢⍵}⊃,`

Comment: @Cowsquack I always forget that trick.

Comment: -1 byte: `{⊃⍒,(+/--/)⊢∘,⌺3 3⊢⍵}⊃,`

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
;€0ZṙØ+SṖ
,ZÇ€Z+$/ŒMœị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FZC7TUNBFERz6iDzkdjP/eyKGojIbDkkQW6AlISADCRkeqABi9ByIaaRx7xoVzv3npnZ56fD4WVZ7v9ef8r2evo@HzeP19PXDdvzm962m9u7y8fD5fP6@74sy243GtbJyahMowc1CcPHnl3T2aidkWShDtogKjEl1mBO0mkVL5gxJrPgVaIJWIhOl2iEY7o4fcVGMisZpICCB6NTjezrZhAyaWTSDdNIIY1aJHYBZSjnxCcRNDE12NZAjdkYRkuG4xJVTslc4lQxZw5ciEkvjEFW2lolNKSeSqhkTlUP/YmWc7//Bw)

<s>Not having convolution built-ins like MATL and Dyalog</s> *Forgetting your language has convolution built-ins* (thank you @dylnan) hurts, but we can do sort of okay without them, partially thanks to `ŒM` and `œị`. First, a helper function to compute neighbors in just one direction, which incidentally transposes the input:

```
;€0Z         Append a zero to each row, then transpose.
    ṙØ+S     Rotate by +1 and −1 (Ø+ = [1,-1]) and sum these.
        Ṗ    Pop the last row.
```

Visually, the computation is:

```
1 2 3   ;€0   1 2 3 0   Z   1 4 7   ṙØ+     2 5 8   0 0 0     S   2  5  8   Ṗ   2  5  8
4 5 6  ————→  4 5 6 0  ——→  2 5 8  ————→  [ 3 6 9 , 1 4 7 ]  ——→  4 10 16  ——→  4 10 16
7 8 9         7 8 9 0       3 6 9           0 0 0   2 5 8         2  5  8       2  5  8
                            0 0 0           1 4 7   3 6 9         4 10 16
```

Interpretation: cell (x, y) of this result is the sum of cell (y, x)'s horizontal neighbors. (For example, here we see that **f(A)[2,3] = 16 = 7 + 9 = A[3,1] + A[3,3]**.)

Then, the main function:

```
,ZÇ€            Pair the input with its transpose and apply helper to both.
    Z+$/        Fold by Z+, i.e., turn [X,Y] into transpose(X)+Y.
                Now we've summed the horizontal and vertical neighbors for each cell.
        ŒM      Find the 2D index of the maximal value.
          œị    2D-index (into the original input).
```

Comment: What about `æc`?

Comment: oh, I didn't know about it :) I'm too busy to golf more so feel free to write an answer using it.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
5BæcµḊṖ)
ZÇZ+ÇŒMœị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DZA9SkRBEITzOUWlYjI907@puanBpmIiewFTkwXNFDyCkZEorGzmYw/yvMizYGZo6Oqvq@b@br9/2Da7Wt5vf7/X49P683bRdsthd7kczi/X59f19Lytp6/1@Pn3@HHDy7Mcti0HdCIKKSjFdEjAFZZt8B2QiQxEhyRGwgVeTRxVCMMQWIcqslAdJk2J6vCJyZbCDcrCMLN5oAThCKKIdeSEKGI2dTjhAxGYCqWgIxTS2ySKi7gxYAV3DNIoG00GaiAVI5AGY4tx6MdaMYihEsbxwuzIRAhGNaeAueiKfgxC5/wBDsY/)

The helper function finds the neighbors of each element in each row. The main function does this to the rows and the columns then finds the element that has the maximum neighborhood sum.

```
5BæcµḊṖ)
5B           bin(5): 1,0,1
  æc         Convolve with [[1,2,9],[other rows]] (for example): [[1,2,10,2,9],...]
    µ        New chain.
       )     Apply this to each element:
     Ḋ       Remove the first element.
      Ṗ      Remove the last element.
             Gives [[2,10,2],...]

ZÇZ+ÇŒMœị   
Z            Zip the matrix
 Ç           Apply helper function
  Z          Zip again. Yields the sum of the vertical neighbors of each element.
   +         Add:
    Ç        The sum of each element's horizontal neighbors.
     ŒM      Find the multidimensional index of the maximal element.
       œị    Index back into the original matrix.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 58 bytes

```
Im@Last[Union@@ListConvolve[{a={0,1,0},{1,I,1},a},#,2,0]]&
```

Convolve the matrix with \$ \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & i & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right) \$, take the element with the largest real part, and take its imaginary part.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZJLaxsxFIX/isCQlUpHb2mRYsgqkEU3XRkvhpJQQ2xDM2QzzG93zifVXQjpXt3nOec8L39ez/Ny@j3f3syjuT2f9y/zx3L4dTldL/v9y@ljebpePq/vn6@HdX5cJ@vstNnV2WfrNjtvdme9nY7Hh9vPv6fLctiZbz/M22F3PJoH831v1nVN2ZpWrQled96sWZ1eOVoTk7wOT5PlFFODNcVtuFZymiJy0VGNpNvpjpP8iq86oRBa@aFCkyeOKk3vJn9RlaSMMDrLiorw@o369U7RqunJVq8mO/eJsnKirKTjFeFkJ2U7IjR/Sn1SRUZZVRZ7slnUXRXVNEWWP6pXGXPq5diQyfVOugvoKCvIX0Fo6nhQQ92KuhZFVt1etlc9jw9cKpFB3qxcx67MpXckU3eYBsa59Y3omgYPga2I1PFk6XhVSG1gzyT89d5u4B3y6EKd1HuDGpnsBAdMC8JMmt29L5zBBjODN2zAAWg0UB0o/tuSXZgObDp6bmAdeke0AEegBrPsAH8wjgJK6LUy6AyeShmaAJOOHEx3jEEcPGC39d2HzsA4kOXvWoUf1AZCd6ZBLXZ873x1/dTBAOyCfucQrNt/TfmhIdSMutEsSoG7WLZtu30B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 127 bytes

```python
def f(a):n=len(a[0]);b=sum(a,[])+[0]*n;print b[max(range(len(b)-n),key=lambda i:b[i-1]*(i%n>0)+b[i+1]*(i%n<n-1)+b[i-n]+b[i+n])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVDLbsIwELz3K7hUSmAi@bm2ofRHIh8SEdqo4CJKpfL16Zj2lOx6dl6X@@39s5hlOUzH1bEZ2m3Zn6bSDL3K7W7cf32fmwF9bjdcrMvucp3LbTX25@GnuQ7lbWoqemy70uJjuu9Pw3k8DKt5O/Zzp/O6mZ/Lq2o3HDf/40vp9GPRlfzYl9zm5dj0vRekCGuQJKPXBuLgPKzmlBx0RLQIOuf2qcKjgeOcEDX4bAU61BMfiTf8GmiLGBBUvTURoiGpUlMoIXgYDa/gHGJCUvBVyZFQQSx14R3Ew/GHNiqtBCSNIAgkJLlUS9oh2HopEIoYhABL64QoBBpXfLQkpCCVA3yCCAw5CTR/WZNBdDAB0YNFGIajM1@jM5ivzXhSJFiFGFkDTI0iBDEnHdKZh2YOdsLjwJqWXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stencil](https://github.com/abrudz/Stencil), 1 + 10 = 11 bytes

Command-line option: `1` compute 1 generation

```apl
y⊃⍨⊃⍒,
+/N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JzUvOzPn/v/JRV/Oj3hVgcpIOl7a@3///xgomj3q3mJopWFooGBspWJopGBopmJkomJgqGBsqWJooGFooWBgrmBv@yy8oyczPK/5vCAA)

`y` from the flattened original input
`⊃⍨` pick
`⊃` the first
`⍒` in descending order
`,` of the flattened

`+/` sums of
`N` the von neumanN neighbourhoods without selves

Comment: Of course there's a language with a one character built-in for the neighbors.

Comment: To be fair, its sole purpose is to solve [these kinds of problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_code "Stencil code - Wikipedia").

Comment: Why is it non-competing?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen [I added](https://github.com/abrudz/Stencil/commit/39cfcdb9f3aea1eade8bd6913888f9345f56f3ee) `y` to the language when I saw that it needed easier access to the original input. Before that, you had to write `(,⍎'input')` instead of `y`.

Comment: @Adám Ah ok, yeah, then it indeed is non-competing. Hadn't noticed the challenge was posted yesterday. If it was an old challenge, non-competing because the language (or language version) is newer [doesn't make it non-competing anymore in the current meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 94 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(p=m=(r,y)=>p=r.map((v,x)=>(s=~r[x-1]+~p[x]+~(a[y+1]||0)[x]+~r[x+1])>m?v:(m=s,o=v)))|o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJLbuMwEET3PkWWElIJ1Gz@egB6DiJoIeSHDOJIsAeGAxi5uqdoKZlNNgRIFtnVr/rPeBwPD/vX@e/d@/T4dHkul7Fsx/vdODdz2ZVmj4@2bOeyvx41R5y4bQ7lc9@f7mS4/Zz7E9dm7D9uZTifu/a65y237Xb3@/ir2ZUDpnJs2/Y8XR6m98P09nT/Nr00z02/ubnpLcMCYkKMCAkS4TuYR/bQNKBKMo89xKA8VpjBElJG6KBxkUiG93AGn@AEOcLxRYAJoiyS2MELgsBFSIeQIbx0CAFplXiHHBB47@AjssAUMcAb0pcXgygSzRmCR4owB1VkB@sWifFlRuqQDLmDy3ABjlu2mReJZkSFsAvWV3jKFUqDlNhqlyUClJ/TMSUKR62DSwg2bIa23Wx@wEkflNbKUilqrFX4V1grEws/YQuESovkRn9RvsuSP/nSKimSL6GyYyOuL0TXnmietth/hSMVoa7/M0gyJxbmQ9sMgokxvaTr@0gIFXtKNU52XskwqxUeUbJtRmS1zzoUhKfUutWfq8A5HOSwZEUsvpL7hl9jzxUrIyLTmgUR2v8pcDV5zhrnjkPFiJmCT1eml38)

#### How?

Instead of looking for the maximum of the sum of the 4 neighbors, we look for the minimum **m** of the sum **s** of their one-complements. This allows us to process undefined values just like zeros, because:

```javascript
~undefined === -1
~0 === -1
```

The inner **map()** is written in such a way that it does not alter the content of the row **r**. Therefore, we can save its result in **p** in order to test top neighbors in the next iteration.

We use:

- `~r[x-1]` for the left cell
- `~r[x+1]` for the right cell
- `~p[x]` for the top cell
- `~(a[y+1]||0)[x]` for the bottom cell

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```
{(,/x)@*>,/(+g@+x)+(g:{(+':x)-|-':|x})x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZLBTiMxEETvfEUdkJghRIzddrt7RkL8B4rEXhKtWIGEOAyC8Ouh2skex1Ptrnrll@3r4fV02s9fw939Oj7ePtzdD5vD42YdN8OBp5ubeR2339ub@Xs9juvx9DF/XT99/rzPe6zL89vLMjzv//z9t6zL5/I@7o5XH09DVbhBMlyvAKQMLSgVkuLTC5LBBC2NS7JdTFDuFdqgitqQFGUKoRVIiyHjIeccUmLUHd7QDHWCnJcYSkF2lIacYIpMfYUnaF@rE0pCTciKNKEaEn9l1EojISgZVkHv9FsUluACrSiOdvbgSHRNS45a0JgyQwTGoFNPxilDm9AcNiEbckXmJ6NZCMSggkTn3CsoFAtkCjbq3SQvr0FO6JMCQaYyIzdUJy3ptLiQf2JJCkiicSVHa1/C3JygUzKjF4KhEU2XDURLeHRESIRHZozl5HFm0I3TI/czYqRPQUj6zeyHOJmb4OmOjFkFa2nSZ5Upg2hr0RLDRXSW0NmQE5ORvUeU6JlshMp8eSJkybYZ9FwCc5cAc@EaTVowI3sCC8wk5P@LzVEmHw4fEd8IeyPg0gis7k6/)

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript ES6, 170 bytes

```
c=g=>{s=0;n=0;f=m=>m||[];for(i=0;i<g.length;i++)for(j=0;j<g[i].length;j++){s=~~f(g[i-1])[j]+~~f(g[i+1])[j]+~~f(g[i])[j-1]+~~f(g[i])[j+1];b=s>n?g[i][j]+!(n=s):b;}return b}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Your code seems to assume that the input is stored in a variable named **g**, [which is not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/58563). You should write either a full program that reads the input or a function (which is usually and by far the preferred way in JS).

Comment: @Arnauld Thank you ! I fixed the code

Comment: You may consider adding a [TIO link](https://tio.run/##VY/NcoJAEITvPoW5QdFa@787QczNl6A4qEECpZACk0vUVydDqVXJYQ/d/c1OT7P93g77vv48L9ruvRw32bjPqmz9M2QibfkdslO2Pl0ueZEeuj6q2apX1fJYttX5I62TJJ7shu1mVeV18UwaTviT2@0Qsb2QRZw3RfKQyX85CSb@SibSXTas27fJmNiXqM2G@HWXXvvy/NW389113Hft0B3L5bGrok2Uz@bznALIwnk4B@shHYwAGQQD7QtMSGDbQBI02xpEIA8fYAW0uyMywBgogvFQEsFB8YQFSTh5R5yAkbASykEK2ADJoYK18A/EKAQLy7mCcQgSpOEsDME/uxCkhudyBGvgHUhBawQFEneEeDLAC3hCEFABykKx5DPDHdEBTkPyFbxfwzCuobkgI/SoyyssNH/OjRnRUMwqKA9LxayI4/EX) to make it easier to test. (I removed the 2nd test case to have the link fit in a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 187 bytes

```java
m->{int r=0,l=m.length,i=l,L,j,S=0,s;for(;i-->0;)for(L=j=m[i].length;j-->0;)if((s=(i<1?0:m[i-1][j])+(i<l-1?m[i+1][j]:0)+(j<1?0:m[i][j-1])+(j<L-1?m[i][j+1]:0))>S){S=s;r=m[i][j];}return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##nZLNbtpAFIX3eYpZGuWAPP8zcZ28QJoNS8SCEpLaNU5kO6kq5GenZyBtzLKVAOEz13Pv@c6tN@@bef3447htNn0vvm6q9nAlRNUOu@5ps92Jh/R4EsQ24@9qvVqL/aygOvLLTz9shmorHkQrSnHcz28PqbgrczTlftHs2ufhO6qywT1qLCn3xdNLlxXVfH6bF7P0/76sy/2qWn9UF/X5qHrKsr7Mqi/yLr/h@VyuV/V6dk2lmcs7Ktcn5SanVv@posLCk3J/rqLCQlbNbpezw7Lsi648y@ti7HbDW9eKrhiPxdnQ69u3hoY@fL2/VI9iTy7Zcuiq9pn2N91zPztzWf7qh91@8fI2LF55OjRt1i62Wbv7KT5gneuEOFiHGKAVohvxR5QKzsBYaPkpRgMZEDS8HE/aODsB/6d27BUtnIdzsB7SweTgzcFA@89egUdsF6FN6hgjoocPsDn0dM4AY6AijIeSCA6Kb1lECTeZ3OUwElZCOcgcNkCyQMHa5OVvmVEIFgRC@8YhSEQNZ2Ei/HS2CEkIHDjCGngCVNAagQzzCS7eEOBz@IiQQwUoC8VH2g@fZTrAaUi64zwahq9o6DzBd3Fige1siknTBcs0FOsVlIeN/x8HZ@ZVaUKZUtAuTcJedjIhkbIRLTMU2iFzenHyYjzmyIxojSkwI4ZCSpGop3hPHGiWFsgtgZUpAj3pxcVgdkTKrGmTgTJ9boLXk3scAab4vE/rQWKJKnOfwGccxMW4Y@KTlo3wNevVxZIzOC4eGZ5zJ1KTyF@EmNYppGgYN3NJmTKCeLldKm0U95m7zaXl2jBN4y9yGa/G428)

**Explanation:**

```java
m->{                           // Method with integer-matrix parameter and integer return
  int r=0,                     //  Result-integer, starting at 0
      l=m.length,              //  Amount of rows
      i=l,                     //  Rows index integer
      L,                       //  Amount of columns
      j,                       //  Column index integer
      S=0,                     //  Largest sum of four cells
      s;                       //  Current sum of four cells
  for(;i-->0;)                 //  Loop over the rows
    for(L=j=m[i].length;j-->0;)//   Inner loop over the columns
      if((s=                   //    Set the current sum to: the sum of:
           (i<1?0:m[i-1][j])   //     Value of the cell to the left, or 0 if out of bounds
          +(i<l-1?m[i+1][j]:0) //     Value of the cell to the right, or 0 if out of bounds
          +(j<1?0:m[i][j-1])   //     Value of the cell down, or 0 if out of bounds
          +(j<L-1?m[i][j+1]:0))//     Value of the cell up, or 0 if out of bounds
         >S){                  //    If this current sum is larger than the largest sum:
        S=s;                   //     Replace the largest sum with this current sum
        r=m[i][j];}            //     And set the result to the current cell
  return r;}                   //  Return the result
```